# Adding javascript file or block to front page only drupal-7

Tags: drupal-7

How will you add any java-script file or block to the front page only in drupal-7??

i know just one function function drupal_is_front_page()?? but it not helpful as per my requirements

```
<?php if ($if_front) { ?>

<script>......</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Not working

Answer (score 4):

You can add this to your theme's template.php file:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if(drupal_is_front_page()) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourtheme') . '/js/your-front-script.js');
  }
}
```